# How to fit a JTable to the size of JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe, layout-manager

I have a frame which is set to:

```
setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Now I have a Jtable and on the Design phase of eclipse I have exactly fitted to the frame:

[image]

But when I run the program I have so much wasted space on the right side as this:

[image]

How can I extend this to fill up the empty space on the right side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make `JTable` fill the available space, put it inside a `JPanel` which has a `BorderLayout` layout manager.

```
JTable table = new JTable();
// Set up table, add data

yourFrame.getContentPane().add( new JScrollPane( table ), BorderLayout.CENTER );
```

UPDATE: as suggested by [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr)

> you don't need the getContentPane(). Since JDK4 you can just add components directly to the frame and then will be added to the content pane automatically.

```
yourFrame.add( new JScrollPane( table ), BorderLayout.CENTER
```

Comment: 1+, but you don't need the `getContentPane()`. Since JDK4 you can just add components directly to the frame and then will be added to the content pane automatically.

Comment: so @camickr it would be `yourFrame.add( new JScrollPane( table ), BorderLayout.CENTER );` ????

Comment: Yes, that is what most people would use since it saves on typing :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But there was a tricky part. I did not use JPanel. I am having a JFrame. I put a borderlayout on the JFrame. and the ScrollPane on the center. Then Table on the ScrollPane and now it is full size.

Comment: @Bernard, `But there was a tricky part. I did not use JPanel.` actually the "content pane" of a JFrame is a JPanel and the default layout for the content pane is a BorderLayout. See the Swing tutorial on [Top Level Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) for more information about the structure of a frame.

Answer (score -1):

If you have just the JTable the following code should work for you:

```
JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
jframe.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
JTable jtable = new JTable();
jtable.setBackground(Color.yellow);
jframe.getContentPane().add(jtable);
jframe.setVisible(true);
```

If you need to add more components to the JFrame I suggest you to use a layout in this way

```
JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
jframe.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();  //chose your favorite
JTable jtable = new JTable();
jtable.setBackground(Color.yellow);
Container contentPane = jframe.getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout(layout);
contentPane.add(jtable);
jframe.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: 1-, This basic answer has already been given. That is take advantage of the default layout manager. Also, you would never add a table directly to the frame. You need to add a table to a scroll pane and then add the scroll pane to the frame in order for the headers to be displayed.